# Preventing multiple clicks from initiating animate

Tags: jquery

I have a div box that if I double click will expand to the entire page. If I press a button that is produced once the div has expanded, the div box will minimize back to its original size. However, if I double click the div box, the event will be triggered twice, expanding the div box then immediately minimizing it. So I tried using .one() but did not realize that it only works once. What could I use to allow only one click at a time without firing multiple events? Here is the jsbin and below is strictly the jquery code. http://jsbin.com/eqezas/3/edit

```
$("#block").one('click', function(){
            $('#block1').hide();
  $("#block").animate({ 
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    fontSize: "3em", 

  }, 1500, function() {
    $('#but').show();  
     });


});


$('#but').one('click',function() {
            $('#block1').show();
      $("#block").animate({ 
    width: "100px",
    height: "40px",
    opacity: 1,
    fontSize: "1em", 

  }, 1500 );
            $('#but').hide(); 
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var processing = false;  // Global variable

// Probably in document.ready:
$("#element").click(function () {
    if (!processing) {
        processing = true;
        $("#element2").animate({"blah": "blah"}, 1000, "easeOutBounce", function () {
            processing = false;
        });
    }
});
```

This way, no matter if you click the original element so many times, it's in a "processing" state until the animation is complete.

Comment: Even when I change one() to on() and use your code, the effect only works once. The multiple events are prevented though!

Comment: I don't see the "double click" problem happening with your original code. I see that it won't allow the maximize/minimize happen more than once (because of `one`). But I don't know what the actual problem is. You need to use some kind of flag, like the global boolean I suggested, to let the program know that it is currently being maximized (or minimized), and that any clicks during those time periods should just be ignored (but you should still `return false;` for the minimize button no matter what).

Comment: If I were to replace the .one() with the .on() and I double click on the minimize button then the effect does occur. I'll play with it some more.